What is wrong with my code? it is getting wrong answer but the std out put is correct
I am trying to solve the Leet Code 189. Rotate Array problem. My code generates the correct output, but after submitting it, it says wrong answer. However, the std output is exactly the same as the answer. I am attaching a screenshot below.
class Solution {
  public void rotate(int[] nums, int k) {

     int arr[] = nums;
     nums = new int[arr.length];
     int idx = 0;
     int l = nums.length;
     
    for (int i = l - k; i < l; i++) {
        nums[idx++] = arr[i]; 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < l- k; i++) {
        nums[idx++] = arr[i];
    }
    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));   
  }
}



I think you are supposed to modify(rotate) the given array itself, not create a new one nums = new int[arr.length] and print that.

I tried that as well. Did not work. If the nums array contains the correct values, why would it give me a wrong answer? Should it matter how anybody chooses to manipulate or create the array?

The issue with your code is that you are reassigning the nums array inside the method (nums = new int[arr.length];)

leetcode doesn't show the part of the code where it's calling the method. Sometimes, the method returns something, but in this case, it doesn't. it passes an array as an argument and expects that same array to be modified because the array outside of this method will have the same changes. For your 2nd question, it depends. here it does.

For future reference, images of text are not well received here. It is more helpful to show text as text, using copy-and-paste to ensure accuracy.

Look at this question and answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Java uses pass-by-value, meaning the method gets a copy of the reference. Any changes to the array elements will reflect in the original array, but reassigning the array only changes the local copy of the reference, not the original array reference in the calling method.
So even if you reffer nums to a new array, the main code still reffer to the old array, which is currently referred by arr in your current code and doesn't hold the right answer.
